# Running code on multiple subdirectories

Tags: python

I have some code that I would like to run on multiple files, each contained in its own subdirectory.  I'd like to write some additional code to ask the user for a subdirectory name, opens the subdirectory, and run the code on a file contained within it (there is only one file contained in each subdirectory). Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you read the docs for the `os` built-in module?  Specifically, you'll find `os.listdir` helpful, as well as `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 0):

with this loop you can manipulate all the file through the subfolders for the root folder

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Your path here'):
    for file in files:
        //your code here//
```